# Generate a pydantic model from pydantic object

Tags: python, streamlit, pydantic

is it possible to create a pydantic model form an instance of a pydantic model, so that the values are maintained ? Something like this:

```
from pydantic import create_model,BaseModel,Field
from typing import Optional

class ExampleModel(BaseModel):
    some_text: str
    optional_number: Optional[float]

instance=ExampleModel(some_text="foo")

dynamic_Model=create_model("Parameters",__config__=instance.Config)
dyn_instance=dynamic_Model()

print(instance)
print(dyn_instance) #this has no attributes so it's an empty line
print("Is it equal ? "+ str(dyn_instance == instance)) #can this be true?
```

If you wonder about the use case. I want to build an web-app with [Streamlit](https://streamlit.io/) and [Streamlit-pydantic](https://github.com/LukasMasuch/streamlit-pydantic). The later reders an UI-inputmask from a pydantic model like this:

```
instance_of_pydantic_model=sp.pydantic_form(model=pydanticModel, key='some key')
```

[See it in action](https://share.streamlit.io/lukasmasuch/streamlit-pydantic/main/playground/playground_app.py)

This leads in a multi-page application to the problem, that the Input_mask will not display any of the user input after switch to another page an back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the create_model function properly it works:

```py
dynamic_Model=create_model("Parameters",**vars(instance))
```

With Streamlit pydantic the input mask stays consistent, even with optional Fields, which are now populated with a value.